# C# How to create custom class like "cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text"

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, struct, enums

**I want to make a notification class or struct**

in which i wanna use something like that:

//sending new notification

```
Notification newnotification = new Notification();
newnotification.Type = NotificationType.FriendRequest;
newnotification.Send("parm1", "parm2");
```

My current trial class:

```
public class Notification
{
    public struct NotificationType
    {
        // i dont know what to put here to add notification types
    }

    public NotificationType Type{ //dont know how to store the type here too }     

    public void Send(string Parm1, string Parm2)
    {
        // i put a code here to send to database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `enum`:

```
public enum NotificationType
{
    FriendRequest,
    OtherRequest,
    ...
}
```

And then you can use it as a type for a property:

```
public NotificationType Type
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And you can use this member like this:

```
Notification n = new Notification();
n.Type = NotificationType.FriendRequest;
```

If you want to save the property value in the database, an addition could be to make it easily convertible from/to `int` like this:

```
public enum NotificationType : int
{
    FriendRequest = 0,
    OtherRequest = 1,
    ...
}
```

You can then easier convert like this:

```
int valueInDB = (int)n.Type; // Will be 0 for "FriendRequest"
```

Other the other way when getting a value from the database:

```
n.Type = (NotificationType)valueInDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need simply to create own **enum**:

```
public enum NotificationType
{
    FriendRequest,
    OtherRequest
}
```

Usage:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public NotificationType Type;
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.Type = NotificationType.FriendRequest;
```

Comment: Thanks Tons :D dont u know how can i store the type in the notification class is that right "public NotificationType Type{}"

Comment: No, you should do it via property: `public NotificationType Type{ get;  set; }` or like I've already written - as simple public member.